# Time Complexity of nested for loops

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Consider the following C function

```
int fun(int n) {
    int I, j;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<n; j+=i) {
            printf(“%d %d”, I, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Time complexity of fun in terms of $Θ$ notation is

1. $Θ(n\sqrt{n})$
2. $Θ(n^2)$
3. $Θ(n \log ⁡n)$
4. $Θ(n^2 \log n)$

---

#### My attempt:

What I understood that outer loop run for $n$ time and inner loop is depend on value of $i$. So, inner loop can not run for $n$ time and it should be $\log n$ time. Option $(3)$ correct.

Somewhere, it explained as:
Time complexity $(n-1)/1 +(n-1)/2 +(n-1)/3 +\dots +(n-1)/(n-1) +1 = n\log (n-1) - \log(n-1) = O(n\log n)$

Good, but how he calculated $(n-1)/1 +(n-1)/2 +(n-1)/3 +\dots +(n-1)/(n-1) +1?$

> Can you explain it, please?
>
> My question is: How he obtained the initial sum?

Comment: Your assumption that the inner loop can't run in $\Theta(n)$ time because it depends on $i$ is incorrect. If the inner loop ran over `for (j=1; j<=i; j++)` the whole code would be $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the question about how he obtained the initial sum, or how he got to the expression $n\log n$?

Comment: @N.Bach, yes, question about how he obtained the initial sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first iteration of the outer loop, $i = 1$ so the  inner loop is:

```
        for (j=1; j<n; j+=1) {
            printf(“%d %d”, 1, j);
        }
```

which is a very simple loop which will execute $n - 1$ times hence the first term in the expression.

For the second iteration of the outer loop, $i = 2$ so the  inner loop is:

```
        for (j=1; j<n; j+=2) {
            printf(“%d %d”, 2, j);
        }
```

which iterates over the odd numbers up to $n - 1$ hence $\frac{n - 1}{2}$ times and the second term.

. . .

For the final iteration of the outer loop, $i = n$ so the  inner loop is:

```
        for (j=1; j<n; j+=n) {
            printf(“%d %d”, 1, j);
        }
```

which will only execute once hence the last term in the expression.

Actually, some of those counts are not exact but the errors are insignificant in an order calculation.

P.S.You are inconsistent about $i$ and $I$ in your code, both C and maths are case sensitive.

Comment: Very good. I was lazy to calculate this one and you help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
(n-1)/1 +(n-1)/2 +(n-1)/3 +\dots +(n-1)/(n-1) +1 &=
(n-1) \left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}  \right) \\
\end{align}
which is $n$ times *something*. That "something" is the sum of the values of $\frac{1}{x}$ at all integers $1, \ldots, n$. And that sum is an upper sum for the integral of $f(x) = 1/x$. So the integral of that function -- which is $\log$ -- is less than or equal to that amount. So the sum you're looking for has
$$
S = n(1 + \ldots \frac{1}{n}) \le n \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x}~ dx = n( log(n+1) - \log(1) ) = n \log(n+1).
$$

The actual claim made -- that you get $n \log(n-1) - \log(n-1)$ is simply not true, but it's a decent approximation.

Anyhow, what I've written shows that your expression is in fact in $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: It should probably be noted that the _something_ is called the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which can be used to find more information about them.

Comment: Thanks, Henning -- I should have said that. Haven't yet finished that first cup of coffee. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes, thanks for nice explanation. I already understood this part.  I asked before this part that "how he obtained the initial sum?"

Comment: You wrote "But how he calculated ...?", which sounded like you wanted to know how he evaluated it. I understand English is not your first language, so it's easy to write something that's at least a little ambiguous. I'm going to leave my answer here just in case someone else someday wants to know about the SECOND possibility. :)